# Custom CSS Not working on Product page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, sass

I'm building a etsy style site using WooCommerce and WC Vendors with the JointsWP framework (Foundation).

On my front-page all the custom Sass is rendering fine. On the shop page it is not displaying. I'm adding the custom coding on content-product.php.

It appears the custom css is being overridden by woocommerce, but I cannot figure out how. Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to figure it out. The woocommerce SASS wasn't being loaded. Once I moved the woocommerce .scss to the assets folder and ran gulp it started working.

Hopefully this helps someone out one day.